# Neo4j REST API Get request from browser vs Get method from REST Client

Tags: rest, neo4j

Neo4j API url is: `http://localhost:7474/db/data`

When I use Chrome visiting this url, which is a GET request. This is the response I got[image: Response page from chrome browsing]

But when I use the restful client such as POSTMAN to make a g request.

This is the response I got.[image: Response from POSTMAN GET request]

My questions are

Both are GET request to the same url. Why Chrome browsing get a html page in return but Postman Request get JSON Response in return.

How Neo4j does that?

Is Neo4j using user agent detection, and if it is a browser visiting, it will give HTML page as response. And if it is a rest client request, it will give json response?

Thanks!

Comment: They use content negotiation headers, primarily `Accept` - for example my request for this site contained the following header: `Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"`

Comment: Thanks Mszymoborski!

I tried setup the Accept header in POSTMAN's GET request, and YES! I got the the html page in return this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use media type negotiation header. For example when requesting this site my browser sends a header like that:

```
Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
```

As you can see it accepts primarily `html`, if that's not available then `xhtml`, then pure `xml`, and if that's not available - it accepts whatever the server can throw at it. `Neo4j`'s website tries to serve content in that order. Postman likely just specifies `application/json`, or nothing at all (the application determines the default media type then), hence the response.